# MySQL Pivot Table - Existance of Primary Key changes Query Results

Tags: mysql, database

MySQL Version 5.7.14 (if relevant). Rewriting to avoid any confusion. This is a very simple / easy to reproduce issue. Tables and their names were obfuscated / generalized.

### STEP 1: Run the following queries in order.

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=5
;

CREATE TABLE `table2` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=5
;

CREATE TABLE `table1_table2` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `table1_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `table2_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `table1_id_table1id` (`table1_id`),
    INDEX `table2_id_table2id` (`table2_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `table1_id_table1id` FOREIGN KEY (`table1_id`) REFERENCES `table1` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `table2_id_table2id` FOREIGN KEY (`table2_id`) REFERENCES `table2` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=7
;



INSERT INTO `table1` (`id`) VALUES
    (1),
    (2),
    (3),
    (4);

INSERT INTO `table2` (`id`) VALUES
    (1),
    (2),
    (3),
    (4);

INSERT INTO `table1_table2` (`id`, `table1_id`, `table2_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
    (1, 1, 3, '2016-12-28 14:47:40', '2016-12-28 14:47:41'),
    (2, 1, 1, '2016-12-28 14:47:37', '2016-12-28 14:47:39'),
    (3, 2, 3, '2016-12-28 14:59:48', '2016-12-28 14:59:48'),
    (4, 3, 1, '2016-12-28 14:51:38', '2016-12-28 14:51:38'),
    (5, 3, 2, '2016-12-28 14:52:33', '2016-12-28 14:52:34'),
    (6, 3, 3, '2016-12-28 14:55:05', '2016-12-28 14:55:05'),
    (7, 3, 4, '2016-12-28 14:56:48', '2016-12-28 14:56:48');
```

### STEP 2: Run this query.

```
SELECT *
FROM `table1`
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM `table2`
    INNER JOIN `table1_table2` ON `table2`.`id` = `table1_table2`.`table2_id`
    WHERE `table1_table2`.`table1_id` = `table1`.`id` 
    AND `table2`.`id` = 3) 
AND `table1`.`id` = 3;
```

**Note that no results are found.**

The combinations (`table1`, `table2`)(1,3),(3,3) do not return results while the combinations (`table1`, `table2`)(1,1),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,4) do return.

### STEP 3: Run this query.

```
ALTER TABLE `table1_table2`
    DROP COLUMN `id`;
```

### STEP 4: Rerun this query.

```
SELECT *
FROM `table1`
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM `table2`
    INNER JOIN `table1_table2` ON `table2`.`id` = `table1_table2`.`table2_id`
    WHERE `table1_table2`.`table1_id` = `table1`.`id` 
    AND `table2`.`id` = 3) 
AND `table1`.`id` = 3;
```

**Note results found.**

---

When running an `EXPLAIN` on this query, I get a warning stating

```
Note: Field or reference 'table1.id' of SELECT #2 was resolved in
SELECT #1 Note:/* select#1 */ select '3' AS `id` from `table1` where
(exists(/*select#2 */ select 1 from `table2` join `table1_table2` where ((`table1_table2`.`table2_id` = 3) and (`table1_table2`.`table1_id` = '3'))))
```

Note that the warning wraps the `table1_id` in quotes (suggesting it sees it as a string).

I'm not sure if this is a bug or something I am doing wrong.

Comment: Reiterating Juan's first comment, please give exact code to reproduce the erroneous behaviour.

Comment: @philipxy Made it as easy as it could possibly be to try it yourself. Run the code, see the results.

Answer (score 0):

I believe mysql is confused about column references.

I believe it will work if you change

```
SELECT * FROM table1 ...... WHERE table1.id = 3
```

By using aliases:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1 ...... WHERE t1.id = 3
```

It is good practice to always use aliases for table references in queries, both for readability and to avoid confusions.

By the way, the query can be written in the following simpler way.

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table1 t1
JOIN table1_table2 rel
ON t1.id = rel.table1_id
WHERE t1.id = 3 AND rel.table2_id = 3
```

It won't make a difference if there aren't duplicate relationships, but here it is using EXISTS.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 0 FROM table1_table2 rel
   WHERE t1.id = rel.table1_id AND rel.table2_id = 3)
AND t1.id = 3
```

Comment: The original query is created in Laravel 5.3 from the query builder and appears to be the standard way it structures those queries. That being said, the inner query is referencing the same table outside of it on purpose and aliasing the table does not fix the query. You can run the creates locally and test the query if you'd like to see it happening.

Comment: Just providing hints. With the information you provide, it seems a bug, but better to discard other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that somehow the foreign keys are mulling the index optimization in MySQL / InnoDB. If you run an explain on the query, you'll notice it uses a type of `index_merge` for the last `DEPENDENT SUBQUERY` only when you use the values that are failing. When you use the other values, the type is `ref`. I do not know the reasoning for the query to switch based on the values, but it clearly makes the results fail. Adding `IGNORE INDEX(table1_id_table1id)` to the join makes the query use `ref` and return the correct result.

```
SELECT *
FROM `table1` t1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM `table2`
    INNER JOIN `table1_table2` IGNORE INDEX(table1_id_table1id) ON `table2`.`id` = `table1_table2`.`table2_id`
    WHERE `table1_table2`.`table1_id` = `t1`.`id` 
    AND `table2`.`id` = 3) 
AND `t1`.`id` = 3;
```

If anyone has more insight as to why the MySQL engine is making these decisions or what exactly is going on here, please explain / post your own answer.

Comment: @philipxy this is not an addition to the question, it is an answer. Although I did not accept my own answer because it lacks a full explanation. It clearly solved the problem in the query, however.